# Converting php by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to use .htaccess to rewrite the all URL of .php to /  under the folder /hkcompany/

Before rewrite:

```
www.domain.com/hkcompany/search.php?typeid=1&crno=F1234&name=ABC+Company+有限公司
```

There are 3 variables for the php url

After rewrite:

```
www.domain.com/hkcompany/1/F1234/ABC+Company+有限公司
```

It may be look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hkcompany/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$  hkcompany/search.php?typeid=$1&crno=$2&name=$3
```

Thank you for help & support !

Comment: What error do you get with the rule you have tried?

Comment: You described what you want to achieve, but not what you actual issue is. We cannot somehow guess that. So you need to tell us ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)